# How to compare two object array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I want to compare these two object array and get the same result as the annotation.
My solution is an overlaid iteration, and I haven't come up with a better solution.

```
   const arr1 = [
     {key: 'cat', name: 'john' },
     {key: 'dog', name: 'james' },
     {key: 'dog', name: 'kane' }
   ];
   const arr2 = [
    {kind: 'cat', sound: 'meow', size: 'small', state: 'angry' },
    {kind: 'dog', sound: 'woof', size: 'big', state: 'happy'  },
    {kind: 'pig', sound: 'oink', size: 'medium', state: 'sad' },
   ];

   const result = arr1.map((ar) => {
     const data = arr2.find(ar2=> {
       return ar.key === ar2.kind;
     })
     const {sound} = data;
     return Object.assign(ar, {sound});
   });

   console.log(result);

   /* result
   [
     {key: 'cat', sound: 'meow', name: 'john'},
     {key: 'dog', sound: 'woof', name: 'james'},
     {key: 'dog', sound: 'woof', name: 'kane'},
   ]
   */
```

I want to know a better solution than this.
How can I solve it? Please let me know.

Comment: it's not a good style, to take an answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58162775/a-better-solution-for-comparing-two-object-arrays-in-javascript and delete the question.

Comment: that link got a page not found issue.

Comment: right, you are missing rep for viewing deleted questions, but it is basically the same quetion and the answer is taken from the answer of this question. so your try is a copy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have the right idea. If you means "better" as a shorter way to write it, here it is :

You can use the `...` spread operator to add a key to the json of the first array. And use of `||` operator to handle the case where there is no matching values.

```js
const arr1 = [{
    key: 'cat',
    name: 'john'
  },
  {
    key: 'dog',
    name: 'james'
  },
  {
    key: 'dog',
    name: 'kane'
  },
  {
    key: 'lama',
    name: 'cartman'
  }
];

const arr2 = [{
    kind: 'cat',
    sound: 'meow',
    size: 'small',
    state: 'angry'
  },
  {
    kind: 'dog',
    sound: 'woof',
    size: 'big',
    state: 'happy'
  },
  {
    kind: 'pig',
    sound: 'oink',
    size: 'medium',
    state: 'sad'
  },
];

const ret = arr1.map(x => {
  const {
    sound = '',
    size = '',
  } = (arr2.find(y => y.kind === x.key) || {});

  return ({
    ...x,
    
    sound,
    size,
  });
});

console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I have one question.
if you have to add size how would you do?

Answer (score 0):

I'd first create an object of `soundsByAnimalName`, whose keys are the animal names and values are the sounds they make, then `.map` the first array and just look up the `animal.key` property on that object:

```js
const arr1 = [
  {key: 'cat', name: 'john' },
  {key: 'dog', name: 'james' },
  {key: 'dog', name: 'kane' }
];
const arr2 = [
  {kind: 'cat', sound: 'meow', size: 'small', state: 'angry' },
  {kind: 'dog', sound: 'woof', size: 'big', state: 'happy'  },
  {kind: 'pig', sound: 'oink', size: 'medium', state: 'sad' },
];
const soundsByAnimalName = arr2.reduce((a, { kind, sound }) => {
  a[kind] = sound;
  return a;
}, {});

const result = arr1.map(
  animal => ({ ...animal, sound: soundsByAnimalName[animal.key] })
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Do note that creating a map of `soundsByAnimalName` reduces the computational complexity to `O(n)` - a nested loop like with `.find` has complexity of `O(n ^ 2)`, which is unnecessary